# SignalR keep alive timeout

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

From SignalR [wiki](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) there is this section on Reconnecting Event

**Reconnecting client event.**

Raised when (a) the transport API detects that the connection is lost, or (b) the keepalive timeout period has passed since the last message or keepalive ping was received. The SignalR client code begins trying to reconnect. You can handle this event if you want your application to take some action when a transport connection is lost. **The default *keepalive timeout* period is currently 20 seconds.**

---

The [section](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeoutkeepalive) on timeouts tells about the three configuration values i.e. DisconnectTimeout,KeepAlive & ConnectionTimeout.

My question is, if I want to decrease the KeepAlive value to say, 5 seconds or increase it to say, 30 seconds, does the Keep Alive Timeout, after which the client starts to reconnect change automatically or would it still default to 20 seconds as mentioned above?

If no, is there a way I could set the keep alive timeout via code?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883263/signalr-long-polling-is-disconnected-in-5-seconds/32966174#32966174