# Migrating ASP.NET MVC application to Node.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, node.js, signalr, edge.js

We're considering migrating our ASP.NET MVC application to Node.js. Here's my current understanding of the migration process.

Our typical action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Something(...)
{
   //1. execute query (for GET) or command (for POST)

   //2. SignalR notification in case POST request

   //3. Return query result (for GET) or void (for POST)
}
```

Perfectly I'd like to move all the web-related code to Node.js (so that we get rid of dead/poorly supported dependencies like SignalR) but keep the logic (queries, commands) on C# (no need to rewrite existing code, easier to maintain than JS). So the best solution I came to (theoretically, did not try it yet) is to call our C# commands/queries from Node.js via Edge.js. I guess there're pitfalls on this way so I'd like to know what you think about it.

Comment: Why do you want to migrate to nodejs at all?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, well... ASP.NET MVC is kinda dead. Especially its opensource community, especially in comparison to Node.js. Here's an example. We found a bug in SignalR. A critical one. That bug has been in SignalR for more than a year, it was reported several times by different people without response, no code has been committed to SignalR repository for almost a year, dozens of issues are not answered, major SignalR committers are committing to Node.js repository (so even Microsoft prefers to invest to Node.js).

Comment: I'm really interested to know about the bug, would you mind linking to the details?  I use SignalR on my site

Comment: It's strange to say that asp.net mvc is dead when they're releasing asp.net5. Besides, signalr != asp.net. If some library is not maintained why not switch to another library?

Comment: I'm voting to close this - not only cause I'm offended that you said that ASP.NET MVC is DEAD.  There are no hard and fast rules for migrating code from one technology to another, we can't know what the precise structure is of the code in your Controller/Action methods so can't comment on what is appropriate, it would have to be on an individual action basis.  Also SignalR has an issue that you've identified but [you were able to get to the bottom of it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33166650/894792) by reverting back a version.

Comment: @Coulton, SignalR has poor behaviour under restricted networks. Here's one of the reports about this bug: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3557

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, by "asp.net mvc" is dead I mean the community itself. And it's basically a fact: both Google Trends and GitHub activity proove this point. Switch to other library that SignalR? I'd like to but do you know any serious alternatives to SignalR for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I see no _death_ [here](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=asp.net%20mvc)

Comment: @Coulton, so you seriously think the situation around SignalR is okay? Dozens of non-responded issues and pull-requests, no commits for a year, etc. So you think it okay if you can revert to a previous version? And what if that version has bugs (and it has) that were fixed in future releases?

Comment: I didn't say that, I said that ASP.NET MVC isn't dead and that you already have a question relating to the SignalR problems.

Comment: @Coulton, adding asp.net to trends will give you a bigger picture: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=asp.net%20mvc%2C%20%2Fm%2F02_qnn&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6

Comment: It's no use without a direct comparison: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=asp.net%2C%20node%20js&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6

Comment: @Coulton, here is a fixed version of your trend: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%2Fm%2F02_qnn%2C%20%2Fm%2F0bbxf89&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6 One thing is dramatically going down and other is going up

Comment: Yes, you've done me now.  There is no possible recourse.

Comment: Apart from this https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=asp.net%2C%20node%20js&date=1%2F2015%2012m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6 :)

Comment: @Coulton, you made the same mistake again. Choose technologies from the dropdown, it makes a smarter search

Comment: Eek!  https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%2Fm%2F02_qnn%2C%20%2Fm%2F0bbxf89&date=1%2F2014%2013m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6  The average volumes over the last 7 days are identical, does that mean that they're both dead? https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%2Fm%2F02_qnn%2C%20%2Fm%2F0bbxf89&date=now%207-d&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-6

Comment: @Coulton, just check out Node.js repositories and appropriate ASP.NET MVC ones. It's like day and night

Comment: Part of me hopes that you're right on this one cause then at least there's something we can agree on :).  I haven't had a look yet though

Comment: It's hard to tell really, there are more commits and contributors on the Node.js repository, but there are also less issues and more closed issues on the ASP.NET MVC one.

Comment: @Coulton, it's hard to find a not-supported major repository in Node.js community. While ASP.NET MVC open source community reminds me zombie apocalypse

Comment: Lol.  It didn't start out as an open source project so its not too surprising.  It's basically a mature product.  It's interesting to hear your thoughts though.

Comment: The reasons why he wants to migrate aren't really important - and were not really part of the question at all. There should be no downvotes because of differences of opinion or loyalty to a particular framework. That said, this question should be edited so that it is a better question - the final phrase sounds as though you're asking for an opinion, rather than facts.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung I agree that the reasons for moving are indeed irrelevant, but what's the question?  What does the OP want to know?  The only answer I can suggest based on the text in the question area is **Try it and see?**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can service your existing c# code as a restful api and use it from your nodejs app.

I think mixing different stuff in one thing will make it more complex, dependent to mixture of things and not maintanable in long term, monolitic in one place more than one thing.

Instead I would seperate my existing stuff as a simple restful api so that you can use it anywhere, deliver and maintain it in its boundary, scalable, service oriented, bla bla..

Answer (score 5):

Although I agree with @Coulton & @VsevolodGoloviznin, But I going to put an answer for this question :)

Look at the [Using Node.js in an ASP.NET MVC application with iisnode](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode) where introduces a mixture of both technologies as you want.

To use proxy, There is a [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). And IIS might be able to do it for you.

**Update**:

[Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) provides a solution to Combine the Node.js with .NET platform by making it possible to call .NET functions from Node.js.

Read the [hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ItsJustASoftwareIssueEdgejsBringsNodeAndNETTogetherOnThreePlatforms.aspx) where contains good topics around this. [Tomasz Janczuk](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/) (he's working on Edge.js) has said:

> Edge.js provides an asynchronous, in-process mechanism for
>   interoperability between Node.js and .NET.
>
> You can use this mechanism to:
>
> - access MS SQL from Node.js using ADO.NET more...
> - use CLR multi-threading from Node.js for CPU intensive work more...
> - write native extensions to Node.js in C# instead of C/C++
> - intergate existing .NET components into Node.js applications